# Rails APIs and path based load balancer routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, microservices, omniauth

We're breaking our monolithic Rails application in to microservices. Our services are hosted on AWS and are behind ALBs. We cannot use host based routing as we are multi-tenant via subdomain, and it would be an SSL nightmare to maintain the required certs for each tenant/environment/service combination. So we are using path-based API routing with rules on the load balancer.  A request looks like this:

`Client -> www.example.com/api/:service_name/the_rest_of_the_path -> ALB -> route to rails service by name of :service_name`

Because ALB cannot modify the path of a request before it sends it on to the serive, when it reaches the Rails services the path is still `/api/:service_name/the_rest_of_the_path` . This means in order to route to the proper controllers/actions in this case,  we'd need to actually create a rails scope on namespace of `/api/:service_name` . This would work in theory but it has two drawbacks.

Firstly it means local developers have to deal with ALB/client specific concerns -- the path used for external service/cluster routing for ALB.

The second is that it couples the application to that path. If the load balancer decided the path should be `/:service_name/the_rest_of_the_path` instead then it would mean changing the application code in conjunction with the load balancer rules to accommodate it. It's not optimal and I'd prefer to avoid it if at all possible.

I thought then perhaps we could introduce a webserver to the mix, in between the load balancer and the application layer. I worked on a proof of concept for this and had it stripping out `/api/:service_name` before it got to the service -- leaving the Rails app with just "the_rest_of_the_path" which is all it cares about. Great! Perfect! Or so I thought.

It works well enough to route initial requests to, It however falls flat when any sort of redirects or links are used by taking the current path (as Rails sees it) in to consideration.

In the event `/api/:service_name` is stripped off before it hits the service, any subsequent links or redirects made from the Rails server itself naturally do not include it in there any longer. You may be on `www.example.com/api/:service_name/foo/bar` but Rails only thinks you're at `/foo/bar`. When it tries to tack something on to the path for a redirect or link like `/foo/bar/baz`, it loses the thing that identifies what service to send it to so the route dies at the load balancer.

This has particularly been an issue with Omniauth/Oauth2 flows for us. Omniauth wants to live at `/auth/:provider` by default. If the request path is actually `/api/:service_name/auth/:provider` then it won't match and the Oauth flow wont initiate. Further if there is a failure with the Oauth flow, Omniauth will hard redirect to `www.example.com/auth/failure`  -- which of course does not resolve as the LB does not know where to route the request to.

If we provide a path_prefix to Omniauth as `/api/:service_name/auth` then it wont match when testing locally at /auth and it won't initiate the flow there.

We won't have control over all of the gems we use and where they redirect to so my question is: Is there a proper way of hanging Rails API microservices off a path on a load balancer, and not have to pull teeth to preserve the necessary prefix in all routes and links and redirects? Something that is essentially a global base href that we can set there, but not set locally so that we can continue to develop at `localhost:3000/path` instead of remembering to use (and coupling with) an LB path like `localhost:3000/api/:service_name/path` ?

Comment: I'm worried this question is too broad as there are so many ways to do this.  However; what are you accomplishing by including the service name in the path?  Can't you just remove the /api/service_name and path based route to whats remaining? /auth/:provider on your LB/gateway goes to your omniauth service and /billing goes to your billing service for example? 

Some alternatives on the client-side discovery realm: include the service name in request headers or use cname's for each service and host-based routing at the ALB. 1 ALB/gateway handles multiple subdomains with cnames.

Comment: Thanks @Datise. I updated the question to explain why we can't use easily host based routing . If we don't have a /:service_name prefix in there then there would be nothing stopping 1 service's path from taking precedence over another service's if they shared the same name. If we don't also prefix that prefix with /api then our public site which is at example.com would erroneously reference a service instead of its own local file structure if it were to link to say example.com/:service_name -- like example.com/orders. Is that the order service or the orders page on the site?

Comment: Headers would work if it were only  machines hitting these APIs but the documentation also lives there and is viewed by browing to example.com/api/:service_name/swagger. Cnames though -- I haven't explored that. Similar to host based routing, wouldn't we need SSL certs for each of those if they were all over HTTPS? So service-a.tenant1.staging.example.com, service-b.tenant1.staging.example.com, service-a.tenant2.staging.example.com, etc. Right now we have a wildcard on *.environment.example.com and its manageable -- not so much if it were multiplied by number of tenants.

Comment: Could still use /api to the microservice fronting ALB to avoid the issue you're discussing? I'm not sure I fully understand the "there would be nothing stopping 1 service's path from taking precedence over another services".  This should essentially just be moving some of the rails router decision making farther to the edge. The rails router is already making some priorities on precedence, no? Microservices are suppose to be responsible for their own resources. so /api/orders would exclusively go to 1 orders service. If you have multiple services with /api/orders I might pause and reconsider.

Comment: As far as cnames go you should still be able to use a wildcard (or possibly multi-domain? I don't remember all the ALB features) at the alb level. You configure the routing with host based rules. I think the drawbacks are mostly: 1 borked cert borks all the subdomains. Doesn't support mutual tls for inter-service communication (if your services communicate internally).....?